# How to overwrite a line at a fixed position if a string in found in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

I have an input file and if any line in that file has a particular key word i want to overwrite the data in a particular column position (say I want to populate column 10 to 15 with `xxxxxx`). I am new to shell scripting. Please forgive if I sound naive.

Sample Input:

```
aaaaa 11 ****** bacxyz more data
bbbbb 11 ****** qweabc more data
ccccc 11 ****** pqrxyz more data
aaaaa 11 ****** jkkxyz more data
```

Expected Output: (If a line has `aaaaaa` at any position overwrite the col 10 to 15 with `xxxxxx` else write as it is.)

```
aaaaa 11 ****** xxxxxx more data
bbbbb 11 ****** qweabc more data
ccccc 11 ****** pqrxyz more data
aaaaa 11 ****** xxxxxx more data
```

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing that would be possible with sed (or perl if you prefer the easy way).

Comment: To be honest, I am just going through some documents on bash scripting, however I could not find any reference to how to do string manipulations specific to a particular column position.

Comment: I know it looks like I am begging to ask you the code (kinda do my work for free), but any pointer or any reference in this regard would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Read in bash documentation about "[Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)", in particular the bit about Substring Expansion. Note that you could also do this with sed or awk, and either of those tools would probably be better (and faster) at this than pure bash.

Comment: @ghoti: I'd say UNIX filters like `sed` or `awk` are as much a part of shell scripting as bash builtins, if not more so.

Comment: @Amadan, Well, we differ on that point. :) POSIX shell needs tools like sed and awk for anything beyond the most basic text processing, but much can be done natively in bash with better performance. Awk and sed are usually considered languages unto themselves (limited in scope, of course), and there are [tag:awk] and [tag:sed] tags for questions that need help with those tools, THIS question included no code at all, and in my view, in its current state, it should be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `sed` may work for you:

```
sed -E '/aaaaa/ s/^(.{16}).{6}(.*)/\1xxxxxx\2/' file
```

```
aaaaa 11 ****** xxxxxx more data
bbbbb 11 ****** qweabc more data
ccccc 11 ****** pqrxyz more data
aaaaa 11 ****** xxxxxx more data
```

btw it is not position 10-15 but 17-22 in your expected output.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks. Could you please explain this part '\1xxxxxx\2`? what's the significance of 1 and 2?

Comment: `\1` and `\2` are back-references of capturing groups #1 `(.{16})` and #2 `(.*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following Vim command:

```
:g/aaaaa/s/\%>16c\%<23c./x/g
```

This will replace characters between columns 16 and 23 with `x`. The replacement is performed in lines that contain the text `aaaaa`.

Answer (score 1):

Column data is usually easy with `awk` - "if the first field is aaaaa, make the fourth field xxxxx; then print the line, whatever it is":

```
awk '$1=="aaaaa"{$4="xxxxx"}{print}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Another global command

```
 :g/^a/norm 3wvt rx
```

Comment: "g" calls global command, "^a" letter "a" at beginning of the line. "norm" normal mode. "3w" jump three words "vt " visual select until next space. "rx" replace the selection with "x". Sorry, but my keyboard is not allowing me to use backticks in order to format the output correctly.